# use of typedef in math3d library

Tags: c++, typedef

in the math3d library , the author has used this following line which has confused me .I was wondering if someone could explain the usage.

```
typedef float   M3DVector2f[2];
```

how can an array be synonymous with a single float?

Comment: It's an array of 2 floats. There's a clue in the name too (2f).

Comment: That's all good.But that really is the first time in c++ , I have come across something so weirdly represented..wouldn't it have been more logical to represent it as `typedef float[2] M3DVector2f ?`

Comment: @nerorevenge Would you declare an array like that `float[2] x;`? Obviously that's illegal, so it would also be illegal for a typedef. Basically it's the same reason you write a[1] not [1]a.

Comment: @john what isn't typedef supposed to be read as synonymous as? Nevermind , I didn't design the language, so I should keep my trap shut.

Comment: That's not how the C++ `typedef` syntax works (admittedly not the most intuitive syntax among computer languages).

Comment: Not really. Think of any variable declaration, put typedef in front of it and now the variable declaration is a type declaration. But the syntax is the same. So because you declare an array as `float a[2];`, you declare a array typedef in the same way.

Comment: @john so float(*)[3] would mean what?

Comment: @nerorevenge A pointer to an array of three floats I reckon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`M3DVector2f` is an alias for a `float` array of 2 elements.

It avoids *excess* typing and giving a *meaningful* name

So you can simply say,

`M3DVector2f point1, point2;`

instead of `float point1[2], point2[2];`

or

`M3DVector2f point3 ={2.3f,-2.1f};`

instead of `float point3[2] ={2.3f,-2.1f};`

Comment: haha no more edits are required, I got the geist of it.I thought it was one of those c type weird tricks where one could get away with weird syntax or weird syntax to scare away noobs like moi.

Comment: Just be wary of using that type in a function parameter. If `M3DVector2f` was a `struct`, you could pass copies around; as it's an alias to an array type, you will always get a pointer to the original data.